# WordPress mySQL - Delete custom post type older than 18 months and custom posts linked to those

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two custom post types 'exhibitions' and 'artworks'. I would like to delete all 'exhibitions' older than 18 months and any 'artworks' attached to those 'exhibitions'.

So for the first part I know how to delete all exhibitions older than 18 months

```
DELETE wp207_posts
WHERE post_type = 'exhibitions'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 548
```

The relationship between an exhibition and artwork are stored in another table named `wp207_p2p` containing the four columns;

1. `p2p_id` ID of the from/to relationship
2. `p2p_from` Post ID of exhibition
3. `p2p_to` Post ID of artwork
4. `p2p_type` for this exercise is `exhibition_to_artwork`

So assuming some kind of join would occur with `wp207_posts` and `wp207_p2p` using exhibition `post_id` from which we can access linked artworks.

The SELECT I have for getting exhibitions and p2p relationships are as follows;

```
SELECT * FROM `wp207_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp207_p2p` p2p ON (p2p.`p2p_from` = wp.`ID` AND p2p.`p2p_type` = 'exhibition_to_artwork' AND wp.`post_type` ='exhibition')
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 548
ORDER BY wp.post_date DESC
```

From this I can see the exhibitions `ID` and the artworks `p2p_to` that need to be DELETED. Exhibitions are returned multiple times based on number of artworks that each has.

How do I go about performing a DELETE based on the above?

Thank you.

Comment: How are the exhibitions attached to artworks. Do they have the same post_id?

Comment: Yes - using Posts2posts connection (http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts) - exhibition_to_artwork

Comment: @user1352792 can you  provide the relation definition of exhibitions and artwork how they are related with in a same table or in different table ?

Comment: I have added relationship information.